# Auto login for gtalk

Tags: linux, google-talk, automatic-logon, empathy

How to achieve auto login and log off on Google accounts on time based . I am using the chat  client is EMPATHY

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you'll need a way to schedule tasks. If you're not familiar with `cron`, and you're using Ubuntu/GNOME then `sudo apt-get install gnome-schedule`. Then you can open **Scheduled Tasks** from the System >> Preferences menu and use the GUI to set a specific time for a command to run.

The simplest way to schedule a time for Empathy to connect and disconnect is to just schedule jobs to start and stop the program (just use the commands `empathy` and `killall empathy`). The problem is that if we kill Empathy without logging out then you'll still appear signed in for a few minutes until Google discovers that you've timed out.

To get around that problem we can use [D-Bus](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/dbus) to send a [signal to Empathy's backend](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/spec.html#org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Connection) that asks it to disconnect. There are lots of ways to do this including with `dbus-send` from the command line, but since I'm more familiar with Python I used that.

Instead of configuring your sign-off task to call `killall empathy`, save the following script somewhere (e.g. `~/empathy_signout.py`) and then schedule your task to call that (`python ~/empathy_signout.py`). *Replace the string* `EXAMPLE` *in the fourth line with your Google Talk account name before you save the file.*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# Disconnect Empathy from Google Talk and kill the program.

# Replace EXAMPLE below with your account name (whatever is before @gmail.com)
google_acct_name = 'EXAMPLE'

import os
try:
    import dbus
except ImportError:
   exit('You need the Python dbus bindings,'
        ' type "sudo apt-get install python-dbus".')

wkname = ('org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Connection.gabble.jabber.' + 
          google_acct_name + '_40gmail_2ecom_2fTelepathy')
pathname = '/' + wkname.replace('.', '/')

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
conn_obj = bus.get_object(wkname, pathname)
conn_obj.Disconnect(dbus_interface='org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Connection')

os.system('killall empathy')
```

This script could be tweaked to avoid the hacky guess of the account name path component, or to sign on also (If quitting the program is a problem). Take a look at the ConnectionManager interface in the [Telepathy D-Bus docs](http://telepathy.freedesktop.org/spec.html#org.freedesktop.Telepathy.Connection) if this stuff doesn't frighten you.