# Linux: How to start Skype (or other program) only when I'm online?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, skype, upstart

I've added [Skype](http://www.skype.com/download/skype/linux/choose/) to my "Startup applications" list, so that it starts automatically after I log in. (This is on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty, with the Gnome desktop)

However, I frequently use my laptop offline, and then Skype is less than useless: it just serves to annoy me with a startup noise and permanently animated toolbar icon.

Is there a way to tell Skype to start only when I'm online? Can I use [Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) to do something like that?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/32658/run-a-script-when-connected-to-a-wireless-network-in-linux

Comment: Consider adding ubuntu to the tag list.

Answer (score 1):

Add a script to your bin directory, and start that script instead of starting skype.

The script will look kind of like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -f
if [[ `ifconfig eth0|grep 'inet addr'` ]] ; then
    skype
fi
```

It's ghetto but it should work.

Comment: perhaps adding this script to autorun should be helpfull

Comment: You can simplify this to `if ifconfig eth0|grep -q 'inet addr'` Still, perhaps not the best way to check for connectivity. It also hard-codes the interface name.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/14352/auto-login-for-gtalk)  might be helpful for you . Actually i have asked this question for empathy chat client . I guess u can do for skype also

Answer (score 0):

Try this script. It uses a `ping` test to determine whether you're online, launches Skype if you are and warns you if you're not:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ping -c 1 -W 5 google.com &>/dev/null;then
    exec skype
else
    echo "No Internet connectivity. Bailing..."
    exit 1
fi
```